# How do I create a local repository for NixOS/nixpkgs?

Tags: package-management, development, nixos, nix, nixpkgs

All the instructions I find for creating a local repository of Nix packages involve creating a local clone of the main `nixpkgs` repository and adding to that.

Is there a way I can create a small repository just containing my local add-on packages?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, just create an expression for the single package. You can get dependencies from nixpkgs by `pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};`.

Answer (score 7):

This blog post have some details: http://sandervanderburg.blogspot.no/2014/07/managing-private-nix-packages-outside.html

For more low-level from-the-ground-up details there's the nix-pill series: http://lethalman.blogspot.no/2014/07/nix-pill-1-why-you-should-give-it-try.html

But I think the basic approach is to create your own version of `~/.nix-defexpr/channels_root/nixos/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix`, say `mypkgs.nix` adding dependencies from the default "repo" by importing `<nixpkgs>`.

Install packages by doing `nix-env -f mypkgs.nix -i DERIVATION_NAME`

But since nix is based on a full-blown language there's infinity ways you could do it I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I'm by no means a Nix expert so I don't know if this is the best way, but it's what I do.  I have a local repo for packages in `$HOME/nix-local`, which contains a number of package files `vault/default.nix`, `blackbox/default.nix` etc and a `config.nix` file which defines `packageOverrides` to call them.  So something like:

```
$ cat nix-local/config.nix
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    vault = pkgs.callPackage ./vault {};
    blackbox = pkgs.callPackage ./blackbox {};
    # ...
}

$ export NIXPKGS_CONFIG=$HOME/nix-local/config.nix
```

You can see the full repo at https://github.com/telent/nix-local

Comment: To anyone reading this since about 2017, this repo is not currently maintained and I would strongly suggest you read up on "overlays", a much cleaner way to do what packageOverrides used to do