# How to use a package revision not yet in the published nixpkgs (but described in the development branches of nixpkgs)?

Tags: compiling, package-management, haskell, nix, nixpkgs

I'd like to use the new release of ghc (7.10, because of a new feature -- `static ptr`), and I'm using a single-user `nix` environment.

I don't find the wanted new release in the published lists at https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html; e.g., the latest ghc's revision points to https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-14.12/pkgs/development/compilers/ghc/head.nix#L37 (it's pre-7.10; but what's the point in using a pre-release, if a stable 7.10 has been released already since then, 2014-12).

But that's the release branch of nixpkgs (`release-14.12`).

Looking into other branches, I can find nix expressions for newer ghc:

- `master` branch of nixpkgs: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/compilers/ghc/7.10.1.nix
- `staging`: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/staging/pkgs/development/compilers/ghc/7.10.1.nix

(Both `master` and `staging` revisions of `ghc/7.10.1.nix` are identical.)

How do I install them into my nix environment (perhaps, with re-compilation)?

Comment: Perhaps, I could simply extract the wanted package from the `master` branch of nixpkgs and add it locally to what is available, like in [How do I create a local repository for NixOS/nixpkgs?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183440/4319)